# Telnet to a port that is already in use

Tags: udp, telnet, tcp

I'm trying to use telnet to check if the port of an application is open.

But i'm receiving the following error: 
Connecting To 192.168.1.10...Could not open connection to the host, on port 3001: Connect failed

I assume the port is closed, but is it also possible the port is being in use by another program? Hence why i'm not able to test using telnet?

Now if this is the case, how come some ports allow simultaneous connections from clients and some don't?

Answer (score 0):

All ports allow simultaneous connections from clients when some program is listing on that port. `Connect failed` means that the port is not listening or a firewall interfered.

You can find out if that port is open by using netstat or on Windows tcpview.